# Sublime Text 3, how to add to right click?

Tags: sublimetext3

How do I add Sublime Text just like how Edit with Notepad++ is there it's nothing big but it saves time.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can click a checkbox labelled ***Add to explorer context menu*** when installing Sublime Text.

If that does not work; here is a thread that goes in depth into how to achieve this: https://sublimetext.userecho.com/topics/3947-windows-context-menu-right-click-edit-with-sublime-notepad-style/

Comment: And you can add an icon to the context menu:
https://bungeshea.com/open-with-sublime-text-icon/

Answer (score 93):

1. Create a new text document with notepad and save it on your desktop
2. Rename it to OpenWithSublime.bat
3. Put this inside:

```html
@echo off
SET st3Path=C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe
 
rem add it for all file types
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%1\"" /f
 
rem add it for folders
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%1\"" /f
pause

rem add it for right click on explorer
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Sublime"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Sublime"         /t REG_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Sublime\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%V\"" /f
pause
```

4. Run it as Administrator

Source: https://gist.github.com/roundand/9367852

Comment: Love running batch scripts so I was able to modify this and added a few other options. It works great for me

Comment: Right click the empty area of explorer does not show the context menu in this way. You need to add `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Sublime]` too.

Comment: There is an easier way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66662987/1559036

Answer (score 25):

Just create a reg file `subl.reg` and open it with a text editor and add the content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Edit with Sublime Text]
@="Edit with &Sublime Text"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe,0"
"MuiVerb"="Edit with Sublime Text"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Edit with Sublime Text\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Sublime]
@="Open with Sublime Text"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Sublime\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe\" \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Sublime]
@="Open with Sublime Text"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Sublime\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe\" \"%1\""
```

You may need to adapt the paths to your Sublime Text installation. This will add Sublime Text when you rightlick on a file, rightlick on a folder background, and rightclick on a folder.
Just double click on the file to add the entries into your registry.

You can always edit and delete those entry by pressing `window+r` and then write `regedit` in that panel. There you will see the same path structure, e.g. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` for right click commands.

Comment: Beautiful. For people who don't know what to do with the .reg file, just open it after you're done editing.

Comment: Amazing, for those who are having a hard time at opening the .reg file with admin permission just save the file, open regedit as admin and go to File>Import

Answer (score 5):

Thanks r-stein for the above answer. But `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Sublime\command]` have some problems. the last argument should `\"%V\""` instead `\"%1\""`.

The full `subl.reg` is

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; show in context menu when right click all kinds files
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Sublime]
@="Open with Sublime Text 3"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Sublime\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe\" \"%1\""

; show in context menu when right click empty area of explorer
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Sublime]
@="Open with Sublime Text 3"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Sublime\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe\" \"%V\""

; show in context menu when right click directory
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Sublime]
@="Open with Sublime Text 3"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Sublime\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe\" \"%V\""
```

Answer (score 4):

Just re-launch the installer.

Click this:

[image]

then check this option:

[image]

Let it finish and you'll now have this:

[image]

Comment: The easiest solution without getting into the intricacies.

Comment: What if you don't have the installer? I.e. I installed the portable version

Answer (score 2):

Create **sublime_contextmenu.bat** file in **sublime_text folder** and put the following contents.

```
@echo off

SET APP_PATH=%~dp0sublime_text.exe
echo %APP_PATH%

echo Add it for all file types
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /ve /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /v "Icon" /d "\"%APP_PATH%\"" /f
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /ve /d "\"%APP_PATH%\" \"%%1\"" /f

echo Add it for folders
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /ve /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /v "Icon" /d "\"%APP_PATH%\"" /f
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /ve /d "\"%APP_PATH%\" \"%%1\"" /f
pause
```

Run as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

**The perfect one for Windows**

1. create a `sumblime.bat` file
2. put the following text into it

sublime.bat

```
@echo off
SET st3Path=C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe

rem add it for all file types
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%1\"" /f
 
rem add it for right click on explorer
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%V\"" /f 

rem add it for right click on explorer
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 3"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st3Path%" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "" /d "%st3Path% \"%%V\"" /f
pause
```

3. Run it as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

You can add sublime text to context menu by using regedit . For more easy step , try batch file script

1. Open notepad and paste this code

```html
@echo off
title Add SublimeText To Context Menu
set/p installedpath=Enter SublimeText Installed Path : 
set/p contexttext=Enter Context Menu Text : 
SET STPath=%installedpath%\sublime_text.exe
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\%contexttext%"
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\%contexttext%"         /t REG_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%STPath%" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\%contexttext%\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%STPath% \"%%1\"" /f
goto done
:done
echo Added To Context Menu
pause
```

2. Save it as context.bat (or any_name.bat) and run as admin. Done

Source : [Narendra Dwivedi - Add Sublime text to context](https://www.narendradwivedi.org/2021/06/add-sublime-text-to-context-menu.html)

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE May 2018:** No longer available, package has been removed.

---

If you have chocolatey, you could just run:

```
choco install sublimetext3-contextmenu
```

Comment: 2019 and this works for me. None of the answers mention a package..?? I used the registry modification answer.

Comment: I tried, but it gave the following errors, sublimetext3-contextmenu not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.