# how to remove sublime option in right click, i used a .bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, sublimetext3

[image: screenshot of open with menu]

**how to remove sublime option in the open with menu. I tried to find .bat file but no progress or say not found it.*

[Sublime Text 3, how to add to right click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839764/sublime-text-3-how-to-add-to-right-click)
from here i used that script.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe you should try this.. work for me**

```
@echo off
@reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"
@reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"
@reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command"
@reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"
@reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3"
@reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 3\command"
```

Comment: still showing option,.....but script was successfully completed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839764/sublime-text-3-how-to-add-to-right-click

Comment: maybe you can uninstall sublime first and reinstall ... the options don't automatically appear if it's not set up

Comment: there is no need to have duplicate commands.  works tho!